# Optimizing a method by moving its dictionary

Tags: python

I have a class `Mammal` which inherits from a class `Animal`. `animal_call(...)` is a method that is defined in the `Animal` class. When the method is called by a `Mammal` object it returns an animals noise from a dictionary that is defined in the `Animal` class. If this dictionary `animalCalls` is going to contain a noise for every animal, that would be pretty large.Now, im not quite sure how long it would take for python to search a dictionary if it had say, 50,000 different values, and thats without having multiple noises to one animal.

So i thought of creating separate dictionaries for each subclass of Animal, `Mammal`, `Fish`, and so on. This would make each dictionary small and faster to search because then a `Fish` doesn't need to know about what a `Moose` says.

The problem i see is that I am not keeping with DRY principles. There would be a repeated, or so i think, method of `animal_call` in each subclass of `Animal`.

Now, I know that end game I will not be hand building further subclasses, for example I hand coded an `Elephant` class that inherits from `Mammal` which inherits from `Animal`. I know at some point ill have these classes built by the program, I just haven't gotten around to that in learning python yet.

I ask this because I see how it could be important to know if splitting up a dictionary is worth it, because of the -slightly- increased complexity, or if its trivial up to a certain size (which i know depends on what is being stored in the dictionary, single values or lists and so on).

Comment: A dictionary lookup is O(1) even with 50,000 values, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Thank you, it seems i need to get back to understanding time complexity. I suppose then my question should be rewritten to ask if violating DRY principles is worth it to reduce time for methods to take. Which is definitely dependent on the method.